# ios7 Tabbar covers tableview

Tags: ios7, tableview, tabbar

I have a new ios7 tabbar app. the app delegate looks something like this.

```
SomeViewController *someView = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *someNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someView];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:someNav, nil];

self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

SomeViewController is a simple view with a full size UITableView embedded. Now when the application runs the tableview will not scroll above the tab bar.

I have tried many many suggestions, such as

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

but nothing seems to work. In IB I turn on the guides and set the height of the table view to be above the tab bar but that doesnt work either.

Rather stuck on something I am sure is very simple.

TIA

Comment: Sadly never did find a solution. Moved to using storyboards instead.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
self.tabBarController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone
```

help?